# R - list of 20,000 addresses in one county and I want to make a density map by block

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe with 20K addresses in one county and ideally want to make a block-level map colored by how many of the addresses are located in those blocks.  Darker colors = more addresses. I have done some very rudimentary mapping but never anything quite like this. I imagine I might need to use US Census data block information or  maybe not?

Any tips on how to get started with this? Thanks!

Comment: the `leaflet` package is a good option http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/ - accepts data.frame, list, geojson, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I am having trouble grouping the addresses by census tract. Any ideas how to do that using leaflet?